# How to send message in flutter whatsapp launcher+url

Tags: flutter

```
var phoneNumber = "917390123456";
var urlString = "whatsapp://send?phone=$phoneNumber";

// Convert the String URL to a Uri object
final Uri url = Uri.parse(urlString);

if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
    await launchUrl(url);
}
```

How can I use the Launcher_url for **IOS**

I get the error:

PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null))

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your `/ios/Runner/Info.plist` file if you want to use external links.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>sms</string>
  <string>tel</string>
</array>
```

You can also use this link : `https://wa.me/$phonenumber`

```
  launchUrl(Uri.parse("https://wa.me/91xxxxxxxx?text=Hello"),
   mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,);
```